# Is there "!include" directive in mermaid files like in plantuml

Tags: markdown, plantuml, mermaid

I use `plantuml` for describing class diagrams and I have a number of `*.puml` files (each for a specific class or set of classes), then I make a single overview file where I include all puml files, like:

```
@startuml ' Overview file for some programm
!include ../SomeLib/ClassA.puml
!include ../SomeLib/ClassB.puml
...
@enduml
```

The question is: does `meramaid` allow us to keep this file structure?

In other words: does it allow to have a number of files and does it have `!include` directive like `plantuml`?.

Thanks a lot for your answers.